# Ajax call URL 404'ing when pushed to staging server

Tags: php, ajax, forms, server

I have AJAX form submission working fine locally. But when pushed to my staging server the process page is 404'ing. I cannot access it directly neither as it 404's but checking on the server and its 100% there with correct permissions too.

The code for the AJAX:

```
$('body').on('submit', '.product-form', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url : '/wp-content/themes/hinge_client_theme/page-templates/template-parts/template-logic/send-form.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : thisForm.serialize(),
        before : $(".error-message").remove(),
        success : function(data) {        
            // removed for question
        },
    });
});
```

That send-form.php is 404ing on the network tab, any ideas whats going on? Working fine locally.

Comment: You should look be using [`admin-ajax.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) and not loading template files directly.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [wp localize script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script). It'll allow you to encode your url into a separate javascript object before your script is loaded. [get_template_directory](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) retrieves the absolute path to the directory of the current theme. Use it in case your WP install directory is different than your local development. The theme directory can also change if the folder is renamed or [WP_CONTENT](https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories) is in a different location.

```
<?php

// Register the script
wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

// Localize the script with new data
$translation_array = array(
    'send_form_php' =>  get_template_directory() . '/page-templates/template-parts/template-logic/send-form.php', 
);
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );

// Enqueued script with localized data.
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
```

Then in your js file you can use:

```
<script>
// alerts 'Path to the send-form.php'
alert( object_name.send_form_php );
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe try this:

```
$('body').on('submit', '.product-form', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url : get_template_directory() . '/page-templates/template-parts/template-logic/send-form.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : thisForm.serialize(),
        before : $(".error-message").remove(),
        success : function(data) {        
            // removed for question
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. Please add some description how this might solve the problem. But note that the `get_template_directory()`  function lives in "PHP land".